# How to have a plugin import UTI types

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plugins

I'm working on a video sharing application that can load plugins that share to different places (Youtube, Twitvid, Facebook, etc.)
I have a plugin that reads in a custom file type. We'll call it a .foo file with some information about the video being shared. So I put this foo UTI type in the imported UTI type section of the plugin bundle's Info.plist.

If I understand correctly, Launch Services looks through the Info.plist and registers the imported and exported UTI types of an app when it opens.

How can I get launch services to register my custom UTI types when it loads the plugin?
Is there an api call I can make to have the plugin register those itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m pretty certain there is no such mechanism. Your app can allow whatever files it wants in open panels, and you can set it to accept any file from Launch Services and reject unknown ones at runtime, but you can’t register types so that, e.g., the Finder considers your app “recommended” for plug-in types but not arbitrary files.

I strongly suggest [filing an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com/).